# How to add back button on ActionBar in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created an app and wanted a back button on my action bar to navigate back to the previous page using Android Studio. I have looked at a number of examples but keep getting errors under `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled`

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: Show what you've tried so far....

Comment: Are you using `Toolbar` using `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: That is the code I have for toolbar  `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that you have a DetailActivity and you need back button to MainActivity. First change your manifest to for DetailActivity

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
      android:value="com.example.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

and in `onCreate` of DetailActivity

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

will fix things. This is the simplest implementation.

Comment: just go to the manifest and find the activity and add <activity android:name=".load_money" android:parentActivityName=".dashboard" />

Comment: It goes to the parent Activity. However, After that, all the views in the parent Activity doesn't work. It doesn't look a good implementation. It can't even implement like back press button.

Comment: It is not related with this question. Check `taskAffinity` of your parent activity.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in `onCreate()`

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Than add this listener in your `MainActivity.java` class

```
protected OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener;

    public interface OnBackPressedListener {
        void doBack();
    }

    public void setOnBackPressedListener(OnBackPressedListener onBackPressedListener) {
        this.onBackPressedListener = onBackPressedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (onBackPressedListener != null)
            onBackPressedListener.doBack();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
}
```

So now in your Fragment class you can implements `MainActivity.OnBackPressedListener` and than:

```
@Override
public void doBack() {
    //Do on back pressed operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity to extends `AppCompatACtivity` and then set `navigationIcon` to your `toolbar` along with `clicklistener`

For example

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_arrow); // Set the icon

        // Icon click listener
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("cek", "home selected");
            } 
        }); 
    }
}
```

Make sure your activity theme is `AppCompat`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<!-- Customization will goes here -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//In Kotlin
// go to AndroidManifest.xml file apply this change

<activity android:name=".PresentActivity">
            // for adding back button on top
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".BackActivity"/>
        </activity>

// Hope this will work.
```

Answer (score 0):

// For add back button on action bar==================
//add this in onCreate method..........

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

//add this below of onCreate Bundle ========

```
     @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item){

    if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home){

        this.finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```